# Perl regex in vim?

Tags: regex, perl, vim

How can I write this perl regex replace command in Vim? (Taken from [this pandoc epub tutorial](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/epub.html)):

```
perl -i -0pe \
's/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg' \
*/*.markdown
```

Comment: can you add an example of what it should match? As written I am not sure how many of the symbols should be escaped. Should `\s*` match "   " or " *"? I am assuming the later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for the `-i -0pe` flags, but the regex:

```
s/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg
```

Would be:

```
s/^Insert\s*\(.*\).png\s*\n\(.*\)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/g
```

Note that you have to escape the capturing groups and that I used `.*` instead of `[^\n]*` in the second capturing group. You don't need a multi-line flag.

Comment: There is a plugin called `eregex.vim` http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3282 which translates from PCRE to Vim's syntax automatically.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of what you are looking for is dependent on what you "magic" setting is set to. see `:help magic` for more info on what charctors vim takes literally.

Answer (score 0):

Make your existing one-liner into a pipeline filter

```
perl -pe 's/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg'
```

Then use `1G!G` or `:%!` in Vim to pipe the current file through that filter, e.g.

```
:%!perl -pe 's/^Insert\s*(.*)\.png\s*\n([^\n]*)$/!\[\2](..\/figures\/\1-tn.png)/mg'
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have perl installed :-(

Comment: Of course. I forget that not everyone can afford to buy perl :-)

Comment: I wouldn't want it for free :-)